# How to disable part of component definition in Template

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a component from Telerik (TreeView) and want to be able to enable or disable a section of the config in my Template to remove some functions. If it would be a regular code i could use a *ngIf but not sure how to. Or is the only wat to do a <dif *ngIf="enableDragDrop"> and have to dedicated fulle templates for this component.

```
<kendo-treeview
    #treeView
        [nodes]="data"
        textField="text"
        formControlName="permission"
        kendoTreeViewHierarchyBinding
        childrenField="child"
        [filterable]="true"
        kendoTreeViewExpandable
        [expandedKeys]="expandedKeys"
        [expandBy]="'text'"
        [kendoTreeViewCheckable]="checkableSettings"
        (checkedChange)="handleChecking($event)"
        [(checkedKeys)]="checkedKeys"
        checkBy="guid"
        
       <--- Section to enable or disable based on value enableDragDrop --->
        kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop
        kendoTreeViewDragAndDropEditing
        (nodeDragStart)="log('nodeDragStart', $event)"
        (nodeDrag)="log('nodeDrag', $event)"
        (nodeDrop)="handleDrop($event)"
        (addItem)="log('addItem', $event)"
        (removeItem)="log('removeItem', $event)"
        (nodeDragEnd)="log('nodeDragEnd', $event)"
        (nodeClick)="log3('nodeClick', $event)"
       <--- End of Section to enable --->
        
        >
    </kendo-treeview>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though, a bit repetitive code, simply turning a boolean with `*ngIf` should be appropriate for this case.

In ts.

```js
enableDragDrop: boolean = true;
```

In html

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="enableDragDrop; else noDragAndDrop"
   <kendo-treeview
        #treeView
        [nodes]="data"
        textField="text"
        formControlName="permission"
        kendoTreeViewHierarchyBinding
        childrenField="child"
        [filterable]="true"
        kendoTreeViewExpandable
        [expandedKeys]="expandedKeys"
        [expandBy]="'text'"
        [kendoTreeViewCheckable]="checkableSettings"
        (checkedChange)="handleChecking($event)"
        [(checkedKeys)]="checkedKeys"
        checkBy="guid"
        
        kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop
        kendoTreeViewDragAndDropEditing
        (nodeDragStart)="log('nodeDragStart', $event)"
        (nodeDrag)="log('nodeDrag', $event)"
        (nodeDrop)="handleDrop($event)"
        (addItem)="log('addItem', $event)"
        (removeItem)="log('removeItem', $event)"
        (nodeDragEnd)="log('nodeDragEnd', $event)"
        (nodeClick)="log3('nodeClick', $event)">
   </kendo-treeview>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noDragAndDrop>
   <kendo-treeview
        #treeView
        [nodes]="data"
        textField="text"
        formControlName="permission"
        kendoTreeViewHierarchyBinding
        childrenField="child"
        [filterable]="true"
        kendoTreeViewExpandable
        [expandedKeys]="expandedKeys"
        [expandBy]="'text'"
        [kendoTreeViewCheckable]="checkableSettings"
        (checkedChange)="handleChecking($event)"
        [(checkedKeys)]="checkedKeys"
        checkBy="guid"
   </kendo-treeview>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Yest that is what I had in mind myself but wanted to avoid the repetitive code. The only good part is it works as the other solution even so cleaner and shorter does not work.

Comment: Imo this is good too, you can understand which component is used by state and its readable and easy to control. Adding attributes dynamically to a component is possible but would overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `boolean` property within the `event binding` execution.

for example :

`let enableDragDrop = false;`

this is the property to use in your `component`.ts

in your `template`, in the tag of `kendo-treeview`:

`(nodeDragStart)="enableDragDrop && log('nodeDragStart', $event)"`

we use `&&` to make sure that the `log()` function will not be executed until `enableDragDrop` is true.

the same goes for the `property` binding

`[kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop]="enableDragDrop"`

it is as easy as this, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This what i was looking for but it seems to not work, when i use the [kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop]="enableDragDrop"  i get the folowing error. Can't bind to 'kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-treeview'.
1. If 'kendo-treeview' is an Angular component and it has 'kendoTreeViewDragAndDrop' input, then verify that it is part of this module.